# How do I fill and filter a dataset for a Crystal Report that comes from a Stored Procedure

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, dataset

Up until today I have always been able to connect my Crystal Reports directly to the Database and I have never had an issue doing so. However I am now in a position where I have to build a report based on a Dataset. I have looked at several tutorials and other posts from SO but all have been doing something slightly different. I think what I have is very close but I am missing some important step because I am not getting any data to show up in my report. Here is the code I have so far.

```
Private Sub RunProductReport(ByVal startDate As String, ByVal endDate As String, ByVal spName As String)
    Dim proReportCon As String = My.Settings.eocon
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(spName, proReportCon)
    da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", Convert.ToString(startDate))
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndDate", Convert.ToString(endDate))

    da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Tickets")

    Dim ds As New dsProductReport
    da.Fill(ds)

    aReport = New ProductivityReport
    aReport.SetDataSource(ds)

    crvReport.ReportSource = aReport
End Sub
```

I have created a DataSet and can view data in the report from the designer (although I am not asked for a parameters so I am getting everything in the database). The Report does open in my application but it is blank at run time so I think I am not filling the dataset with new data. I have the da.Fill(ds), which I think should fill the DataSet but it isn't and I am not sure why.

And as I mentioned my Parameters are being ignored - Most of the sample code I found used Select Statements inline (instead of a stored proc) so I may not even be close on this one but it compiles and based on what I read seems like it "should" work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you put a breakpoint after the `da.Fill(ds)` and your dataset is empty?

Comment: Try `aReport.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))`

Comment: I did try the breakpoint. It says that there is a count of two records but I can never see the data. However I am not sure if it isn't there or I am just not walking down the right path in the Locals tree. I keep opening nodes and seeing the same type of data over and over.

Comment: I Set DataSource as you suggested and I a still getting nothing on the report. So I don't think the data is ever getting to the dataset. I admit I don't understand a lot of what there is to know about the debugger but I can usually find my data if I poke around enough. I am not finding it so I don't think it is there. Anything obviously wrong with how I am setting that?

Comment: I've a working function to get data from a SP to a DataSet. Let me find it so you can see which part is failing (the sp, the report or both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this function returns a dataset with the data from a SP or a raw query.

```
Public Function getDataSet(ByVal query As String, ByVal isStoredProcedure As Boolean, ParamArray Params() As SqlParameter) As DataSet
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dataSet As DataSet = New DataSet

    Try
        If isStoredProcedure Then sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        sqlCmd.CommandText = query
        For Each sp As SqlParameter In Params
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(sp.ParameterName, sp.Value)
        Next
        sqlCmd.Connection = New SqlConnection(MyConnectionString)
        dataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCmd
        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Table")
        sqlCmd.Connection.Close()
        return dataSet
    Catch ex As Exception
        If sqlCmd.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then sqlCmd.Connection.Close()
    End Try

    Return False
End Function
```

You can call it as:

```
 Dim ds As DataSet = getDataSet("MySP or Query", True, New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@MyParam", MyParamVaue))
```

And it goes

```
aReport = New ProductivityReport
aReport.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))

crvReport.ReportSource = aReport
```